# Baked smoke domain jumps back to origin when being moved

Tags: fire

I have this project of a large scale environment, and have the main character in front, and he's supposed to be holding a torch. I made the fire smoke domain, and got it baked. But it's at the world origin and I'm trying to move it to the torch.

When I try, it just jumps back to the origin. and I tried freeing the bake cache and then I could move it. but when I baked it again, it put it back at the world origin. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it able to be moved if parented to an empty and then moving the empty?

Comment: It sounds like you have accidentally added a location keyframe at the origin, possibly at frame 0, to your smoke domain.  Is this the case?

Comment: It might be helpful if you created a blend file for just the fire that reproduces the problem. If you added that blend file to your question, we might be able to figure out what is going on.  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I'm attempting to upload the file right now, and I did all the steps to do so, but then it said "There was an internal error attempting to complete your request."